Run Script on machine where repo is
I currently try to run a script with Azure Pipeline on the machine where my repository is.
I tried already with different types of tasks like Bash@3 or ShellScript@2 but if I echo in the script i get always get this error

[error]Not found scriptPath: /home/vsts/work/1/myFolder\project\script.bat

My server where I cloned the git repo with the script I want to run is a windows server and not sure how to properly access it.
- task: ShellScript@2
  inputs:
    scriptPath: $(Agent.BuildDirectory)/myFolder\project\script.bat

thats how my task looks like in the yaml file.
Can you guys help me, what I am doing wrong?
I tried different task types like Bash@3 or ShellScript@2 and get the same error. If I do the tree command in a script like
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    filePath: ''
    arguments: ''
    script: |

      echo tree
      
      tree $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)

and I get there my script.bat file in the output but dont know how to run it

Can you try once with BatchScript@1 task, I always use this one to run bat files, though it's also possible via other Azure DevOps tasks.
- task: BatchScript@1
  displayName: 'Run bat script'
  inputs:
    filename: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\..path to..\script.bat'


if I try this i get this error message: ##[error]The current operating system is not capable of running this task. That typically means the task was written for Windows only. For example, written for Windows Desktop PowerShell.
It seems for me, thtat it wont try to run the script on my server, where I cloned the repo with the srcript, but somewhere else and I dont understand where.

It depends on whether you want to run script.bat in the local repo or script.bat in the Azure repo. Refer to the following steps:

Set up a self-hosted agent on your local machine and run your pipeline using it.

Use BatchScript@1 task to run your batch file.

If you want to run the script.bat in your Azure repo, set filename to $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/{the path of batch file in the repo}. In my example, it's $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/script.bat.


If you want to run the script.bat which is in your local repo, the filename will be the path on the local machine. For example, E:\MyRepo\TestBatch\script.bat.




Agent.BuildDirectory is the local path on the agent where all folders for a given build pipeline are created. Build.SourcesDirectory is local path on the agent where your source code files are downloaded.
For example, I configured my self-hosted agent in E:\**Agent\vsts-agent-win-x64-3.236.1 folder, then the value of Agent.BuildDirectory is E:\**Agent\vsts-agent-win-x64-3.236.1\_work\1  and the value of Build.SourcesDirectory is E:\**Agent\vsts-agent-win-x64-3.236.1\_work\1\s. See more info from predefined variables.

Update
If you want to use Microsoft-hosted agent, you can use PowerShellOnTargetMachines@3 task to run your local script.
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- task: PowerShellOnTargetMachines@3
  inputs:
    Machines: '{The target machine FQDNs or IP addresses}'
    UserName: '{User login}'
    UserPassword: '{Login password}'
    InlineScript: 'cmd.exe /c "E:\MyRepo\TestBatch\script.bat"'

This task uses Windows Remote Management (WinRM) to access on-premises physical computers or virtual computers that are domain-joined or workgroup-joined. You need to set up WinRM on your local machine and configure your local network to allow the access from MS-hosted agent. See the network of the MS-hosted agent from this doc. You can see the detailed info about the prerequisites of this task from Prerequisites.
In addition to this, you can also use SSH task to run shell commands or a script on a remote machine using SSH. You need to create a SSH service connection and ensure that your local machine allows MS-hosted agent to access it.
Because Azure DevOps uses the Azure global network, IP ranges vary weekly. You need to regularly configure the network between the MS-hosted agents and your local machine. It is recommended that you create a new machine in the same network as your target server, and then use this machine as a self-hosted agent to run your pipeline.

I want to run it on my local repo. Is there another way than set up an agent? I am missing permission to install the agent on the local machine (its a server)

If you want to use Microsoft-hosted agent, you can use PowerShellOnTargetMachines@3 task or SSH task to run your local script. See the detailed info from my answer above.
